# startNativeTracing to profile a native android Library

Tags: android, android-ndk, profiling, native, trace

I am trying to use the `startNativeTracing` method from the android `Debug` class and I can't find the output anywhere.

I'm running my app in the provided emulator from the android ADT bundle, with the command line option `-trace ericcv`. I call `Debug.startNativeTracing()` in `onResume` and `Debug.stopNativeTracing()` in `onPause`.

I have also tried using `f9` to stop and start the tracing. The console prints out "start tracing" and "stop tracing" but I have no idea if a tracefile is created and if so, where it is.

I read the emulators sdcard while it was running using the adb shell and there wasn't anything new there. If it helps at all I am trying to use this tool to profile the OpenCV library while its being run by the face-detection sample.

Update:
Unfortunately there is no trace file where I started the emulator. I noticed an error message in Logcat saying: "error opening trace file: No such file or directory". Does anyone know where the native tracer is looking? I have tried creating the files "ericcv.trace" and "ericcv" is the directory where I start the emulator from but this does nothing. 
Thanks

Comment: Error message in logcat is probably https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-dev/libs/utils/Trace.cpp line 48 -- different sort of tracing, one not supported on the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace file is on the host system, not on the emulated device.

(edit)

It's under the AVD configuration directory.  For example, if I start the SDK emulator like this under Linux:

```
./tools/emulator -trace fubar @Simple-AVD
```

Then the trace data will be in `$HOME/.android/avd/Simple-AVD.avd/traces/fubar/`.

Once you have the traces, you'll need to use the `tracedmdump` shell function, defined in `build/envsetup.sh`, to convert the output to traceview format.  ([Some notes about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539932/how-to-view-android-native-code-profiling).)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no trace file where I started the emulator. I added some info to the question

Comment: You're right, it moved.  I updated the answer with the new location.

Comment: Found it! Thank you! I would vote up your answer but I don't have enough stack-rep yet