# Interpreting Android emulator trace file

Tags: android, android-emulator, profiling, qemu

I am trying to profile the Android browser. In the browser's source code, I added [Debug.startNativeTracing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#startNativeTracing%28%29) and [Debug.stopNativeTracing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#stopNativeTracing%28%29) to tell the emulator to enable/disable qemu tracing. After making, in the Android source code directory, I started the emulator using

```
$ emulator -trace foo
```

and obtained the trace files in `out/target/product/generic/traces/foo/`.

According to this post: [How to View Android Native Code Profiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539932/how-to-view-android-native-code-profiling)  The way to interpret the trace files is to use `tracedmdump`. However, I encountered this problem:

```
$ tracedmdump foo
post-processing traces...
bash: post_trace: command not found
***
*** Error: malformed trace.  Did you remember to exit the emulator?
***
```

I found the source code for `post_trace` in `sdk/emulator/qtools/` but it seems that it was never compiled.

Did anyone ever have the same issue? Or is there any suggestion on the app profiling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am interested in same information. This is a useful question.